# Automount LUKS encrypted USB HDD with keyfile auth in Mint/Cinnammon

Tags: encryption, mount, linux-mint, luks

My external backup HDD is LUKS encrypted and can be mounted with password or key file. When plugged in, Cinnammon asks me for a password and mounts it to /media/user/drivename. I want to change authentication to keyfiles.

- I added a keyfile a slot on the USB drive
- I edited crypttab accordingly

Now, when I plug the drive in, I hear the notification sound, the drive appears in Nemo, but when I click on it, it says "Operation alredy pending". When I edit /etc/fstab and set a static mount path, it gets in the way of the automatic mounting even more.

**Is there a way to integrate keyfile-based LUKS-authentication in the automatic mount mechanism of Linux Mint 16/Cinnammon?**